# Prove $\bigcup_{q>p}L_q[0,1]\subsetneqq L_p[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Especially I want to know how to construct $f\in L_p[0,1]$ and $f\notin \bigcup_{q>p}L_q[0,1]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are in a space of finite measure $L^q \subset L^p$. Take then the sequence 
$$q_n = p+\frac 1n \to p$$ 
and take functions 
$$f_n(x)=x^{\alpha_n}\,.$$
You now want to choose some negative $\alpha_n$ such that
$$\alpha_n\left(p +\frac 1n \right) > -1 > \alpha_n \left(p +\frac{1}{n-1} \right)\,,$$
so that for each $n$, the function $f_n$ belongs to $L^{q_n}$ (and to $L^p$) but not to $L^{q_{n-1}}$. An easy computation shows you that this can be done.

Define then
$$f(x) = \sum_n \frac{1}{2^n}\frac{f_n(x)}{\|f_n\|_p}\,.$$
This one is $L^p$ but not $L^q$ for all $q>p$. Indeed its $L^p$ norm is less than $2$, while for any fixed $q>p$ you find $n: p<q_n<q$, so that $f_n$ forces the $L^q$ norm of $f$ to explode.